# Openvpn client stopped to work on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vpn, openvpn

My openvpn client stopped to work on Windows 7 64bit. User reports that there was "blue screen of death", then after reboot Openvpn stopped to work.

1. client keys are valid. I copied them to other client machine and could connect to VPN
2. I can telnet openvpn server from client
3. Route looks fine
4. Client can connect to server according to logs, but smth weird happens during key exchange...?
5. Windows TAP device is installed.

How can I debug it?

Here are client logs:

```
Sun Nov 01 01:39:17 2015 us=29232 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1446331157,WAIT,,,
Sun Nov 01 01:39:51 2015 us=45177 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
Sun Nov 01 01:39:51 2015 us=48177 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Sun Nov 01 01:39:51 2015 us=48177 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Sun Nov 01 01:39:51 2015 us=48177 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1446331191,RECONNECTING,connection-reset,,
Sun Nov 01 01:39:51 2015 us=48177 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
Sun Nov 01 01:39:56 2015 us=48463 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Sun Nov 01 01:39:56 2015 us=48463 LZO compression initialized
Sun Nov 01 01:39:56 2015 us=48463 WARNING: normally if you use --mssfix and/or --fragment, you should also set --tun-mtu 1500 (currently it is 1400)
Sun Nov 01 01:39:56 2015 us=48463 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1476 D:140 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Sun Nov 01 01:39:56 2015 us=48463 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Sun Nov 01 01:39:56 2015 us=48463 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1446331196,RESOLVE,,,
Sun Nov 01 01:39:56 2015 us=51464 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1476 D:1450 EF:44 EB:143 ET:32 EL:3 AF:3/1 ]
Sun Nov 01 01:39:56 2015 us=51464 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1476,tun-mtu 1432,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,comp-lzo,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
Sun Nov 01 01:39:56 2015 us=51464 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1476,tun-mtu 1432,proto TCPv4_SERVER,comp-lzo,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
Sun Nov 01 01:39:56 2015 us=52464 Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'ef060fcc'
Sun Nov 01 01:39:56 2015 us=52464 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '249a8e18'
Sun Nov 01 01:39:56 2015 us=52464 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443 [nonblock]
Sun Nov 01 01:39:56 2015 us=52464 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1446331196,TCP_CONNECT,,,
Sun Nov 01 01:39:57 2015 us=52521 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443
Sun Nov 01 01:39:57 2015 us=52521 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Sun Nov 01 01:39:57 2015 us=52521 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443
Sun Nov 01 01:39:57 2015 us=52521 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1446331197,WAIT,,,
```

Here are server logs:

```
Sun Nov  1 03:21:23 2015 us=68907 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Sun Nov  1 03:21:39 2015 us=96170 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Sun Nov  1 03:21:39 2015 us=96481 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Sun Nov  1 03:21:39 2015 us=96540 LZO compression initialized
Sun Nov  1 03:21:39 2015 us=96742 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1576 D:140 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Sun Nov  1 03:21:39 2015 us=96814 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1576 D:1450 EF:44 EB:135 ET:32 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Sun Nov  1 03:21:39 2015 us=96918 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1576,tun-mtu 1532,proto TCPv4_SERVER,comp-lzo,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
Sun Nov  1 03:21:39 2015 us=96946 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1576,tun-mtu 1532,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,comp-lzo,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
Sun Nov  1 03:21:39 2015 us=96996 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '3e6d1056'
Sun Nov  1 03:21:39 2015 us=97030 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '31fdf004'
Sun Nov  1 03:21:39 2015 us=97108 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:65204
Sun Nov  1 03:21:39 2015 us=97153 TCPv4_SERVER link local: [undef]
Sun Nov  1 03:21:39 2015 us=97182 TCPv4_SERVER link remote: [AF_INET]YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:65204
Sun Nov  1 03:22:00 2015 us=905345 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:65191 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Sun Nov  1 03:22:00 2015 us=905550 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:65191 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Sun Nov  1 03:22:00 2015 us=905719 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:65191 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
Sun Nov  1 03:22:00 2015 us=905759 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:65191 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
Sun Nov  1 03:22:00 2015 us=905835 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
```

Comment: There's too many things this could be when file corruption is likely. Completely uninstall the client, reboot, reinstall. If it still fails you need to check windows integrity.

Comment: Hi, corruption of what file? Copied keys are valid, I tested them on other machine. I already tried to reinstall openvpn client and reboot. What else could I check? What is "windows integrity"?

Comment: If the disk is mid write and you get a BSOD, you can get corruption anywhere. Open CMD prompt, enter "sfc.exe /scannow" and hit return. It'll take a while, but may fix it.

Comment: Hm... I got 3M text file and plenty messages where something was repaired and something wasn't. I  ve tried to search for 'vpn'/'openvpn'. Didn't find any mention. What should I search there for?